# .click() on Selenium causing error on page

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to automate add to cart when a Item is available. I find the button using By.Class and then click on it to add to my cart. When I run my code it find the button and tries to click on it. When it does I get a message on the site "error trying add to cart" i cleared all cache and cookies but i get same problem.
ps. it worked the first few times when i was debugging i manged to get it in the cart but eventually it stopped adding to the cart.

```
   package Scraper;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Scraper {
        public static void main (String[] args ) throws InterruptedException{
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Gardu\\eclipse-workspace\\Scalper.java\\src\\drivers\\gecko driver\\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/msi-radeon-rx-6800-16g-16gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-graphics-card-black-black/6441020.p?skuId=6441020");
            driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/xfx-amd-radeon-rx-6800-16gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-gaming-graphics-card-black/6442077.p?skuId=6442077");
            boolean foundButton = false;
            while(foundButton == false) {
                WebElement currentValueBuy = driver.findElement(By.className("add-to-cart-button"));
                if (currentValueBuy.getAttribute("class").contains("btn-disabled")) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    driver.navigate().refresh();
                    //with the new page find the button and brag it value to see if it contains "disabled"
                    currentValueBuy = driver.findElement(By.className("add-to-cart-button"));
                }
                else if (!currentValueBuy.getAttribute("class").contains("btn-disabled")){
                    //we terminate the loop and click on the good button
                    currentValueBuy.click(); 
                    foundButton= true;
                }
                
            }//end while loop

            //we cant click on the prompt so refresh to get out of that window
            
            System.out.println("he buaght");
        }
 }
```

Comment: your while condition never get satisfied on the base on the given url and it will go with the infinite loop. Update it

Comment: I added foundButton =false; at the end of the: if(statement){ } and it started working again. ?